# Get undefined when trying to read response returned from API in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

In React ... I am trying to read the response return from API and get undefined, what is the problem?

Undefined occurs when calling the function `retrieveItems()` from the component.

```
**// item service class** 
import axios_o from 'axios';

class ItemService {
  retrieveItems() {
    axios_o.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => {
        return  response;
      }).catch();
  }
}
```

```
**// component calling the item service** 
import React from 'react'
import ItemService from "../Services/ItemService";

class Posts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.itemservice=new ItemService();
    **console.log(this.itemservice.retrieveItems())**
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Posts List</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default Posts;
```

Comment: `retrieveItem` is not returning the axios result. Keep in mind it's a `Promise` so it's working asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ItemService {
 retrieveItems() {
   return axios_o.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
     .then(response => response)
     .catch(error => error)      
  }
}
```

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.itemservice=new ItemService();
  this.itemservice.retrieveItems().then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

Comment: the added return won't make this any more synchronous, will it?

Comment: thanks aviya for your answer , I have a question . can we say that we must use "then" in case of calling function that contains API call ?

Comment: @DeVYaGhI Well the `then` part is mandatory because of the ajax call. I can't think of any API call that would not be ajax since that would mess up the application always waiting for a server response. So probably the then is needed.

Comment: @aviya.developer Many thanks my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment the method `retrieveItems` is not returning a value. To fix this return the axios call

```js
retrieveItems() {
       return axios_o.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
             .then(response => {
                 return  response;
             }).catch(
         );
}
```

or rewrite it to async/await for better readability

```
async retrieveItems() {
  try {
    return await axios_o.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  }catch(e) {
    // do some error handling or move the try/catch to caller side
  }
}
```

Now in your console log you should see not the real response of the API call but a Promise. To get the real response you also have to wait for the answer on caller side:

```
class Posts extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.retrieveItems()
    }

    retrieveItems = async () => {
        this.itemservice=new ItemService();        
        const response = await this.itemservice.retrieveItems()
        console.log(response)
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Posts List</h1>
        );

    }
}
```

With this you should see the response in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the typical pitfall of wanting to return something from within a callback function to the outer function. That's can't work, because the outer function (`retrieveItems`) has already finished. You need to stay in the asynchronous pattern. The easiest is probably this:

```js
import axios_o from 'axios';

class ItemService {
  retrieveItems() {
    return axios_o.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  }
}


import React from 'react'
import ItemService from "../Services/ItemService";

class Posts extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.itemservice = new ItemService();
    this.itemservice.retrieveItems().then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    });        
  }

  render() {
    return (<h1>Posts List</h1>);
  }
}

export default Posts;
```